# Use php to generate div and select with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have some jquery question :

First my php code :

```
<?php
 for($C=1; $C <= 9; $C++)
{
    echo '<div id="couvert_'.$C.'" style="width:100px;height:30px;float:left;padding-top:10px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:10px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px;cursor:pointer;text-align:center;background-color:#dfdfdf;">'.$C.'</div>';
 }
?>
```

I generate 9 div element.
I would like to generate jquery script to :
- select one of those div
- change background color of my selected div with #FF7E15
- let the others div with background color #dfdfdf

DO you have an idea ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Little suggestion: avoid to add all this CSS code inline. Use a class to style this `div`.

Comment: @AndreasFurster it is unique. It's appending the iteration count to the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end of your php script use this jquery script:

```
<script>
//now maybe you want to change the selected div with the mouse?
$("div").click(function(e){
//loop over the divs and set them to the std. color
$("div").each(function(e){
    $(this).css("background-color","#dfdfdf");   
});
//set the current clicked div to the right color
$(this).css("background-color","#ff7e15");    
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your proposal. And if I want tu "unclik" the div selected do you know how can I do that ?

Comment: you mean with a second click on it put it back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.convert').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#FF7E15');
      });
  })
  </script>
```

```html
<?php
 for($C=1; $C <= 9; $C++)
{
    echo '<div class="convert" id="couvert_'.$C.'" style="width:100px;height:30px;float:left;padding-top:10px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:10px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px;cursor:pointer;text-align:center;background-color:#dfdfdf;">'.$C.'</div>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mad answer

**PHP**:

```
<?php
 for($C=1; $C <= 9; $C++)
 {
    echo '<div id="couvert_'.$C.'" style="width:100px;height:30px;float:left;padding-top:10px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:10px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px;cursor:pointer;text-align:center;background-color:#dfdfdf;">'.$C.'</div>';
 }
?>
```

**jQuery + PHP**:

```
<?php
  $magicElement = 3;
  echo "$(\"#couvert_" . $magicElement . "\").css(\"background-color\", \"#FF7E15\")";
?>
```

Comment: Nobody said **clicked** element. :P